# how is the definition of 'Commit...', 'Apply Patch' and 'Share Project' in Eclipse for SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn

Everytime before connecting to svn server, there are 2 'Team' options to choose: 'Apply Patch' and 'Share Project'. Both options seem to perform the same when intializing the svn project.

In addition, how is the functional difference between 'Commit...' and 'Apply Patch'?

What exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The apply patch is used to add changes saved into a diff file (that is the patch) to the current file/project. Such patches are used e.g. for summarizing changes that can be moved independently of version control systems, such as added as a Bugzilla attachment.

Share project is used to upload the project to an SVN server.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the difference between apply patch and commit... ?

Comment: When you apply a patch, the local working copy gets changed. When you commit, the changes in the local working copy gets uploaded to the server.

Comment: Do you mean when applying a patch, the local working copy will be updated (/reverted changes) from server?

Comment: No. Patches are independent of the SVN server. A patch is a diff file, that describes some changes. If you apply the patch, the project in your workspace will contain these changes. This works even if your projects is not versioned using SVN (or other VCSs).

So applying a patch the local working copy will be updated from the patch - not the server.

The data on the server is not changed in any way, until you commit the changes.